# Ajax function won't redirect my page upon completion

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax function that should redirect the page upon completion. At this point, I don't care if it's on a success or fail, so I have it in .always(). It'll execute anything else I put in there, like an `alert()` statement or a `console.log()` statement. But, for some reason, `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` or `window.location.href = ("http://stackoverflow.com");` don't make anything happen.
There are no errors in the console either.

Here's the ajax:

```
function createAdd(event, user){  // Creates a custom event and automatically gives creator ownership
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
   var loc = document.getElementById('loc').value;
   var start = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
   var end = document.getElementById('datepicker2').value;
   var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
  var jqxhr = $.ajax( "/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/", {
   type: "POST", 
   data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user}
   })
    .always(function() { window.location.replace("/eventsearch/eventsearch"); 
    alert("hello") })
}
```

The alert executes.

Comment: replace() is a string function. Just set the value using equals.

Comment: There's something else going on here.. can you please create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Never made a Fiddle before, but here is what I have. Let me know if you need me to change something. http://jsfiddle.net/n22dX/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.replace("/eventsearch/eventsearch")
```

should be

```
window.location = "/eventsearch/eventsearch";
location.reload();
```

Comment: Still nothing happening :/

Comment: Does it throw an error? Have you tried it with a full URL rather than a relative path?

Comment: No errors are thrown. Neither absolute nor relative URLs do anything. The form just resets its fields and submits.